# I need make a cover up when a text file is loading into a form

Tags: multithreading, java-me, load, alert

I am working on a j2me application and I need to wait for a text file into a form. This takes at least 27 seconds and varies. I would like to use an alert to tell the user to wait until the text file is loaded. Is there any way to reduce the time taken to load the text file or is the a way of implementing the alert?

Comment: what have you tried? did you happen to use [splash screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) before - not in Java ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alert with a guage as progress indicator, if you don't want a progress indicator and just want an alert as a busy indicator then don't use a gauge. However giving feedback to the user is always good. Here is a link on how to do this:

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/alerts20/index.html

On a different note, 27 seconds seems like a lot of time. How big is your text file? how are you processing it. Perhaps this can be optimised as well. Post code snippet if that is an issue.